# How do I save a graph and a table to one file(PDF, JPG, PNG, etc) from Jupyter Notebook so that the table is next(on the right) to the graph?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plotly

I have taken the utility bill and decided to run it through Jupyter Notebook for fun.

This is what I imported in the first cell:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
```

There are two dataframes: ***cost_annually*** and and ***cost_annually_for_table***.

```
list_of_annual_cost = [costfor14, costfor15, costfor16, costfor17, costfor18, costfor19, costfor20, costfor21, costfor22]
final_annual_cost = []
for i in list_of_annual_cost:
    new = (i/total_cost)* 100
    final_annual_cost.append(round(new, 2))
# dictionary with list object in values
annual_cost = {
    'Years' : ["2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"],
    'Cost': [costfor14, costfor15, costfor16, costfor17, costfor18, costfor19, costfor20, costfor21, costfor22],
    'Total Cost': total_cost,
    '% of TC': final_annual_cost
            }
  
# creating a Dataframe object 
cost_annually = pd.DataFrame(annual_cost)
cost_annually
```

> > > *sidebar: costfor16, costfor17, etc are variables from earlier cells in the code representing the total cost for the years 2016, 2017, etc*

The latter is a copy of the former, where ***cost_annually_for_table*** had its numeric columns converted to strings so I could add the dollar signs back and remove trailing zeros- it's for presentation.

***Cost_annually*** is for all of the fun stuff so the datatypes for **cost** and **total cost** columns are floats.

This cell is where I am a bit befuddled:

```
ax1 = cost_annually.plot.bar(x='Years', y="Cost", rot=45);
fig =  ff.create_table(cost_annually_for_table)
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=200,
)
fig.write_image("table_plotly.png", scale=2)
fig.show()
```

The first line is the bar graph and everything else is for the table. However, the table is run first and then the bar graph...so the table is on top of the bar graph.

I removed the first line and added it as the last line of code but the table is still on top of the bar graph.

How do I put the table next to the graph(on the right of the graph) from Jupyter Notebook and save these two images in one file?

I appreciate your time.

*This is the sample data from 2014*
[image]

***This is how it looks in the Jupyter Cell***:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you present sample data and current output? Data and figures may help us get a quicker response.
Is there any reason why you would not use a subplot of the plotly?

Comment: I am not sure how to use a sublplot of the plotly but I will upload the data and figures asap. @r-beginners

Comment: Please refer to the official reference for [examples](https://plotly.com/python/figure-factory-subplots/#horizontal-table-and-chart) of table and chart subplots.

Comment: Thank you, I've made some progress. I have the table next to what is supposed to be the bar graph. However, I just have an empty field where the bar graph should be. I'll have to figure out how to get the table to the left. I haven't found that solution in this documentation yet. @r-beginners

Comment: for instance, what is "xaxis='x2'"? What does x2 mean? @r-beginners

Comment: `xaxis='x2'` refers to the x-axis on the right.

Answer (score 1):

```
df
###
   Years     Cost  Total Cost  % of TC
0   2014  3247.85    26949.14   0.1205
1   2015  3018.08    26949.14   0.1120
2   2016  3084.52    26949.14   0.1145
3   2017  2768.78    26949.14   0.1027
4   2018  3421.73    26949.14   0.1270
5   2019  2893.52    26949.14   0.1074
6   2020  2986.25    26949.14   0.1108
7   2021  3280.47    26949.14   0.1217
8   2022  2247.94    26949.14   0.0834
```

```
df_plot = df[['Years','Cost']].copy()
df_table = df.copy()
df_table['Cost'] = df_table['Cost'].apply(lambda x: "${:}".format(x))
df_table['Total Cost'] = df_table['Total Cost'].apply(lambda x: "${:}".format(x))
df_table['% of TC'] = (df_table['% of TC']).apply(lambda x: "{:.2%}".format(x))
```

```
# table
fig = ff.create_table(df_table)

# plot
# Unmark if we want color variate with 'Cost'
# fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_plot['Years'], y=df_plot['Cost'], xaxis='x2', yaxis='y2', name='Cost', marker_color=df_plot['Cost']))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_plot['Years'], y=df_plot['Cost'], xaxis='x2', yaxis='y2', name='Cost', marker_color='#41bf9b'))
fig.update_layout(title='Cost Annually',
                  height=600,
                  margin = {'l': 5, 'r': 5, 't': 100, 'b': 2},
                  xaxis = {'domain':[0, 0.45]},
                  xaxis2 = {'domain':[0.55, 1]},
                  yaxis2 = {'anchor':'x2'}
                  )
fig.show()
```

[image]
The graph includes two-part
Table and Barchart, you only need to specify `domain` to arrange the layout.
`axis` are floating area in a fixed canvas, adjust their size via `domain`.

```
# table
fig2 = ff.create_table(df_table)

# plot
fig2.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=df_plot['Years'], y=df_plot['Cost'], xaxis='x2', yaxis='y2', name='Cost', marker_color='#41bf9b'))
fig2.update_layout(title='Cost Annually',
                   height=600,
                   margin={'l': 5, 'r': 5, 't': 100, 'b': 2},
                   xaxis={'domain': [0.55, 1]},
                   xaxis2={'domain': [0, 0.45]},
                   yaxis2={'anchor': 'x2'}
                   )
fig2.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to switch the position of the graph and the table? I've been looking at the plotly documentation and haven't seen a way to do so.

Comment: I've updated my post, you can check how it rearranges sequency.

Comment: thank you. At a first glance the only difference is that you switched the values between `xaxis` and `xaxis2`. The concept of domain isn't intuitive to me yet and I haven't found documentation that helps me get it...it hasn't clicked yet. But based off your code. `.55` is a little more than half and that is where the bar graph is. `.45` is where the table is but I don't understand the value of `1` or why `xaxis=x2` for the Bar parameter doesn't translate to the bar being on axis 2. Does my confusion make sense @BaronLegendre?

Comment: Yeah, you’re right, I’ve ever used tableau, it creates graphs one by one, if you wanna give a meeting to demonstrate a report with multiple charts/tables, we have to create an empty canvas and arrange blocks first(like block_1 on top with 30% of screen and block_2 on the bottom with 70% of the screen), after setting layout, and now we just start to put content inside these blocks. The same thing happens in front-end engineering setting CSS layout. And Plotly actually renders all tables and charts with java-script and CSS underhood.

Comment: gotcha, so is it better to use tableau > matplotlib? I did some cursory searches on matplotlib and seen some reddit threads say it's not all that...but it's the creme de la creme for 2d work.

Comment: In my opinion, Plotly is much easier and faster than Matplotlib, For personal work on the Jupiter notebook, we would use `Plotly` to **see** how it looks as quick as possible, for this purpose, we don't wanna spend lots of time on making pretty plot with Matplotlib. and the daily reports would use `Plotly Dash` or `Streamlit` which would be hosted on a server in the Cloud. `Tableau` or `Powerbi`(they also could be hosted on the Cloud) is used for a very firmly daily report or presentation in pitching or huge meeting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247010/discussion-between-fitzgerald-and-baron-legendre).